# Recipe Tag Classification with Machine Learning Algorithms

Tags: python, json, tags, svm, prediction

I'm doing a project that where I have about 15,000 sample recipes with Title Ingr(edients), Summary, Prep, and Tag in a JSON file.

A sample recipe looks like this:

{

```
"title": "Turtle Cheesecake",
"summary": "Cheesecake is a staple at the Market, but it’s different nearly every day because we vary the toppings, crusts, and flavorings. Cookie crusts are particularly good with cheesecakes. If you prefer your cheesecake plain, just serve it without the topping",
"ingr": [
  "1½ cups graham cracker crumbs",
  "½ cup finely chopped pecans (pulse in a food processor several times)",
  "6 tablespoons ( ¾ stick) unsalted butter, melted",
  "1½ pounds cream cheese, softened",
  "¾ cup sugar",
  "2 tablespoons all purpose flour",
  "3 large eggs",
  "1large egg yolk",
  "½ cup heavy cream",
  "2 teaspoons pure vanilla extract",
  "1 cup sugar",
  "1 cup heavy cream",
  "½ teaspoon pure vanilla extract",
  "½ cup coarsely chopped pecans, toasted",
  "2 ounces semisweet chocolate, melted"
],
"prep": "To Make the Crust:\n\n\n\n Grease a 9-inch springform pan. Wrap the outside of the pan, including the bottom, with a large square of aluminum foil. Set aside.\n\n\n\..."
"tag": [
  "Moderate",
  "Casual Dinner Party",
  "Family Get-together",
  "Formal Dinner Party",
  "dessert",
  "dinner",
  "cake",
  "cheesecake",
  "dessert"
]
```

},

I want to know of any algorithms or methods to classify this data with the end goal being an ability to predict tags based on the other four classes. I'm new to machine learning and haven't really worked with JSON files and don't have that much Python practice.

Comment: You want to look at a suggestion or recommender system: [Kaggle has a 101](https://www.kaggle.com/gspmoreira/recommender-systems-in-python-101) for these and [Data Camp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/recommender-systems-python) has a few classes. Beyond that, people on SO will be more likely to answer if you give code showing what you have attempted. As the question is now, this currently can be considered a "shopping question" which tend to generate too many opinionated answers and may be put on hold because of this.

Comment: Note, there is also a [tag for this on DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommender-system) so problems related to designing it (as opposed to programming it) may do better there if [they follow the site guidelines](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour)